# Bluetooth not working in Linux Mint 18

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Linux Mint 18, my bluetooth icon is appearing but it cannot find any devices when searched for. The output for `dmesg |grep -i blue`

```
[   12.730623] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   12.730638] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.730641] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.730642] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.730647] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.001534] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   13.017244] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   13.017250] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   13.109889] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   13.109895] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   15.115993] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   21.870946] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.870950] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.870954] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   56.510615] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   56.510623] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   56.510628] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

As you can see the output is shows the patches `BCM.hcd` are not found and the hci0 command are saying timeout

```
[   13.109889] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   13.109895] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   15.115993] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly how it doesn't work. What happens?

Comment: does `hcitool dev` output show a `hci0`?

Comment: The output to `hcitool dev` shows this `Devices: hci0 9C:AD:97:DB:EB:1C`

Answer (score 9):

Just installed Linux Mint 18.1.  Bluetooth speaker would not pair.

Went to software manager and installed package "[Blueman](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/blueman)" then went to "all applications" from "Menu", right clicked "Bluetooth" then "uninstall".

Blueman icon showed up on "Panel", clicked on it, followed the very intuitive menu and within about one minute my Bluetooth speakers worked fine. Be sure and go to "sound settings" and select the speakers.

Very simple.

Comment: Yeah works great (mouse and keyboard), but then after a few hours, suddenly connection lost and refuses to reconnect. Eventually mysteriously reconnects after incessant retries.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove blueberry && sudo apt-get install blueman` — one command better that thousand words

Comment: Any idea what we can do if your very simple instructions don't work? blueman just hangs on 'Pairing in Progress' forever

Answer (score 2):

Just install [Blueman](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/blueman) package instead of default [Blueberry](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/blueberry)

```
sudo apt-get remove blueberry
sudo apt-get install blueman
```